# A problem of periodic functions , the greatest common divisor and a lattice

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to solve the following problem.

If $\psi(s) = \frac{s(s-1)}2$. I write $f(s,k) = (\psi(s),\psi(s-k))$, where $k$ is a fixed positive integer. Let $K$ be the image of $f_{s,k}$. If $s>3$ and $k>1$

- Show that $f_{s,k}$ is periodic and in particular $K$ is finite. This is the same as showing that $f_{s+t,k} = f_{s,k}$ for some $t$.
- Show that $K$ has a greatest element $g$ and a least element $1$
- Show that $K$ is the divisor lattice of $g$.
- Is it true that $3|g$ ?

Here are some initial values:

- $f_{s,2} = 1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,3,....$ so $K=[1,3]$
- $f_{s,3} = 1,3,3,2,3,3,1,6,3,1,3,6,....$ so $K=[1,2,3,6]$
- $f_{s,4}$  and $f_{s,5 }$ we have $K=[1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30]$
- $f_{s,6}$  we have $K=[1,2,3,5,7,15,21,35,105]$
- $f_{s,7}$  we have $K=[1,2,3,4,6,7,14,21,28,42,84]$

Also I am assuming "periodic" is the correct term here used to describe $f_{s,k}$

Comment: Computations suggest that $g(k)=n(2n+1)(n+1)$ or $n(2n+1)(2n-1)$, depending on whether $k$ is odd or even. It might help to use the fact that $\psi(s) = \sum_{i=0}^{s-1} i$, from which it follows that $\psi(s)=\psi(s-k)+\sum_{i=s-k}^{s-1} i=\psi(s-k)+ks
+\frac{k\cdot(k-1)}{2}=\psi(s-k)+\frac{k}{2}\left(2s
+k+1\right)$.

Comment: @SteveKass I can sort of follow your response. I am not sure what $g(k)$ is though?

Comment: By $g(k)$, I meant the greatest element of $K$ ($K$ being the image of $f_{s,k}$ for a given $k$). I should have said the following: When $k=2n$ is even, $g(k)=g(2n)=n(2n+1)(2n-1)$, and when $k=2n+1$ is odd, $g(k)=g(2n+1)=n(n+1)(2n+1)$. For example, you show the largest value of $K$ to be $84$ for the sequence $f_{s,7}$. There, $7=2\cdot3+1$ is odd, and my formula says $g(7)=g(2\cdot3+1)=3\cdot4\cdot(2\cdot3+1)=84$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I thought that was what you meant by $g(K)$ glad that is clear now. Curious you appear to have a formula for $g(K)$ any suggestions on the finiteness of $K$ itself? If we can show that $K$ is finite then we know that it has a least and greatest element.

Comment: Assuming your $g(K)$ is correct then from (Ethan D. Bolker, Elementary Number Theory: An Algebraic Approach. Mineola, New York: Dover Publications (1969, reprinted 2007): p. 7, Problem 6.5.) for odd $k$ we have that $g(K)$ is divisible by 6 and so it is divisible by 3.

Comment: The sequences you’re looking at are the diagonals in this triangle: https://oeis.org/A256095. Your question seems like the kind of question someone would have worked on, but I can’t find anything.

Comment: Is 30 in the sequence you referenced,  in particular say $f_{s,4}$?

Comment: Yes. $f_{s,4}$ is $1, 1, 6, 10, 1, 3, 2, 2, 15, 1, 2, 6, 1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 3, 10, 2, 3, 1, 2, 30, 1, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 1, 30\dots$, and $f_{s,5}$ is $1, 3, 1, 10, 15, 1, 1, 6, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 15, 5, 2, 3, 1, 5, 30, 1, 1, 3, 10, 5, 3, 1, 2, 15, 5, 1, 6, 1, 5, 15, 2, 1, 3, 5\dots$.